# Why is using Ubuntu 18.04 as the docker host about 2x faster than Debian 9?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, docker, google-compute-engine

We are running the same docker container on two different Google Compute VMs. Both VMs have the same specs. The docker container uses Debian as the base image, runs python, and performs a number of CPU-bound and IO-bound operations. The only difference between the two VMs is the host operating system - Ubuntu 18.04 on one VM and Debian 9 on the other. I was under the impression that the speed of our process should be almost identical for both VMs. I thought that it might be a bit faster on Debian 9 because it is more lightweight than Ubuntu. The reality was the exact opposite. Our process runs approximately 2x faster on the Ubuntu VM compared to the Debian VM.

What are some possible reasons for why this may be the case? Is Ubuntu's kernel significantly faster than Debian in some situations?

Comment: CPU-bound operations don’t depend much on the OS, so what kind of IO are you doing? I believe Ubuntu has the best support for Local SSDs right now, if you’re using those.

Comment: @Dan Just some reading and writing of files. That doesn't seem to be the bottleneck, but yes we are using local SSDs.

Comment: Depending on what kind of PD or SSD storage size are being used, this could play a role in I/O and R/W performance:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance